# R division result is not precise

Tags: r

```
> 52631579 - 52631559
[1] 20
> 20 / 52631559
[1] 3.800001e-07
> 52631579 / 52631559
[1] 1
> class(52631579 - 52631559)
[1] "numeric"
```

I would like the division to result in the precise float.

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f

Comment: The division is in "precise float" whatever that is supposed to mean. See the R help for `print` and `print.default`. Use `options(digits=15)` for example to display 15 significant digits.

Comment: `dput(52631579 / 52631559)`. R doesn't always show all digits.

Answer (score 1):

you can use `sprintf` function to format output

```
sprintf("%.50f", 52631579 / 52631559)
# [1] "1.00000038000014401795567664521513506770133972167969"
```